# Delete permission is granted for user to database but mongrel server shows Mysql::Error: DELETE command denied to user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Delete permission is granted for user to database but server shows Mysql::Error: DELETE command denied to user. I am using mongrel server for rails. When I login to mysql with same user credentials delete is permited.

Comment: Have you verified permissions are correct for all hosts the user is on and/or run FLUSH PRIVILEGES?

Comment: Ya, I did FLUSH PRIVILEGES. But, when I restarted the server, delete started to work. Not sure why I needed to restart the server.

Comment: Have you verified the host IP hasn't changed and/or that the user is allowed to connect from any host - a restart might have changed ip if the server doesn't have a static one.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **sudo** before the command.